# Is it possible to update the Salesforce's Auto Response Rules' Rule Entries in bulk?

Tags: case, metadata, migration-tool, email2case, case-auto-response

I need to update the "Sent From (Email)" of all the rule entries in Case Auto-Response rules. Is it possible to do that all together since I have 400+ rule entries using Data Loader or some other method?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [ant migration tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/meta_development.htm) for that purpose.

To retrieve and update ALL auto-response rules the following lines should be present in `package.xml`

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>AutoResponseRules</name>
</types>
```

if you want to specify auto-response rule for concrete SObject

```
<types>
    <members>Case</members>
    <name>AutoResponseRules</name>
</types>
```

if you want to specify only concrete auto-response rule for concrete SObject

```
<types>
    <members>Case.test</members>
    <name>AutoResponseRule</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve that just by using REST API call?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it's part of the metadata API and as such needs to use the package.xml method of doing it.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE @NeilMelecio! Converted your answer to a comment as it didn't directly answer the question, and would have likely been closed (and removed) by the community.